# How can position: fixed; be used correctly in CSS so that the block can be displayed on the entire screen?

Tags: jquery, css

There is a screen that needs to be clicked and popped out. POP is pressed on the top of the whole screen. I set the following CSS:

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

However but it did not cover the entire screen.

I searched the Internet and found that it was because the parent layer had a
`transform` setting that prevented the pop from covering the screen, but on the parent layer I had to use the `transform` so I couldn’t remove it.

I wonder if you can do anything about it? I wrote a demo that I encountered a problem and would like to ask everyone to help me. Thank you everyone

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log(666)
  $('.pop').toggle();
  
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    $('.pop').css('display', 'none')
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrap {
  transform: translate(20%, 20%);
}

.pop {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  display: none;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.close {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">click pop</a>
    <div class="pop" style="display:none;">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>hello world!!</h1>
        <a class="close" href="javascript:;">X</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is entirely caused by the use of `translate`. For what reason do you ***have*** to use it? There are a lot of alternative ways to re-position elements.

Comment: *but on the parent layer I had to use the transform so I couldn’t remove it.* --> then you have no way to do what you want